# PHP - reduce CPU usage while processing images

Tags: php, cpu-usage

I have a function which uses Imagick to make the 3D effect of a 2D image (fake perspective).
I have to process about 10-30 images at once and here's the problem.
I am worried about CPU usage, because my service provider has limit to 60 seconds of a CPU usage.

I want to use CRON to generate for example 5 images per minute.
I've thought about other solution - use sleep to give some rest to the CPU. Am I right or it's just my stupid idea?

What would you do?
Service Provider is OVH and the service is simple hosting.

Sorry for my English,
Chris from Poland :)

Comment: Use the `at` system to schedule the jobs sequentially. script processes an image, then schedules itself for immediately execution via `at`, and that next script does another image, schedules itself via `at` again, etc...

Comment: That's option. I could do a list of images - for example create some table containing images to process and simply execute script using CRON task.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems and want to decrease imagemagick CPU usage...

First, you can try to optimize the way you use it, for example, if possible :
- use an API wrapper instead of command line calls
- do several transformations in a single 'convert' command
- ...
Source : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/api/#speed

Then, to control CPU usage of imagemagick, and impose limits to system resources used (and many ither things), you can set a security policy file
Source : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php

Or you can try to do the same thing directly using environment variables, like "MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1" or "MAGICK_THROTTLE" (set in system env for command line or directly in PHP script for example)
Source : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment

Please read also as a beginning these interesting posts about it : http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20130
http://www.azanweb.com/en/high-cpu-load-when-converting-images-with-imagemagick/

Hope this will help!